# Add inline style in reactjs without using JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add inline style to the element using reactjs. I found

```
var divStyle = {
  color: 'white',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')'
};

ReactDOM.render(<div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
```

in reactjs docs. Thing is, it is not working without JSX.

I tried doing this.

```
return (
        React.DOM.div({ className: 'eventsOuter'},
              {style:'divStyle'}
        )
```

But the style part is not working.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe {style: divStyle} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass variable instead of variable name:

```
React.DOM.div({
    className: 'eventsOuter',
    style: divStyle
}, 'Hello World!')
```

Also you can compile online:
[on the babel website](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0Avar%20divStyle%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20color%3A%20'white'%2C%0A%20%20backgroundImage%3A%20'url('%20%2B%20imgUrl%20%2B%20')'%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%3Cdiv%20style%3D%7BdivStyle%7D%3EHello%20World!%3C%2Fdiv%3E%2C%20mountNode)%3B%0A)

Comment: "You need to pass variable instead of variable name" is quite confusing. I think you mean - You need to pass a variable instead of the string of a variable name