# How do I set the style of children using css modules in a reactjs project using classNames and JSX

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, auth0

I am setting up a project with React JS and want to use auth0 to handle authentication (and maybe some serverless functions).

auth0 provides a nice "seed" project https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-sample that works basically out of the box.

The code for the main container uses JSX and loads css style from a module file. The module file provides the className classes that are used for styling.

I am extending the bootstrap layout with React-Bootstrap components, and am able to style some components using classNames syntax.

For example, I am styling a Navbar's background color like this:

Appending to the css module file `/01-Login/src/views/Main/styles.module.css`

```
.mainNavBar{
        background-color: rgb(45, 140, 210);                                                    
        border-color: rgb(45, 140, 210);                                                        
}
```

Then to the file containing JSX `01-Login/src/views/Main/Container.js`

```
<Navbar className={styles.mainNavBar} fixedTop>
...
</Navbar>
```

However, when I try to style other inner elements, ie the text color,

I tried:

```
.mainMenuItem { 
        color: #fff;
}
```

And:

```
 <NavItem className={styles.mainMenuItem} eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
```

It doesn't work. I think it is because I don't know how to reach the children of NavItem.

I tried this and variations of it:

```
.mainMenuItem ul > li > a { 
        color: #fff;
}
```

But it just doesn't seem to be the right way to do it, and doesn't work ( though an 'li' item got styled with the color at some point when inspected on the browser, but not the 'a' ...).

Finally, I tried inline styles (see related question [Add inline style in reactjs without using JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720650/add-inline-style-in-reactjs-without-using-jsx)) but this seems to suffer from the same inheritance problem.

Thanks so much if you can point me in the right direction as I am confused.

Edit 19/07/2016

Looks like NavItem doesn't get the style elements...

I submitted an issue to react-bootstrap:
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used inline styles with javascript syntax with [Radium](http://stack.formidable.com/radium/) instead of passing standard css with the "Classname" attribute.